# How to display a pdf file using PDFBox in JPanel?

Tags: pdf, netbeans, pdfbox

I have already created a JForm in netbeans which can read pdf file using PDFBox. But the problem is that I have used the method PDPage.convertToImage() which is really very slow. Can anyone please help me in displaying the pdf using PDFBox in the JPanel at a faster speed ?

The code I have written is inside an ActionListener for a JButton.

```
File f = null;
ArrayList<JLabel> jl = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
BufferedImage bi = null;
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int x=fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if(x==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    f=fc.getSelectedFile();
}
        PDDocument doc=null;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(f);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not done\n"+ex);


    }
    List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    Iterator itr = pages.iterator();
    int q=0;
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        PDPage page = (PDPage)itr.next();
        try
        {
            bi = page.convertToImage();
            q++;
            jl.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
    itr = jl.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        viewPanel.setVisible(false);
        viewPanel.add((JLabel)itr.next());
        viewPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done");
```

Answer (score -2):

NetBeans has several plugins to display PDFs

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/5809/java-pdf-reader
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/11676/netbeans-pdfviewer
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/17/pdf-viewer-javafx-converter-and-bookmarking-application

HAve you tried any of them?

Comment: I don't want my netbeans to read the pdf file. Instead I want my application designed in netbeans to read the pdf file.